# Python requests POST BytesIO

Tags: python, matplotlib

Есть функция, которая рисует график с использованием matplotlib и создает объект `plt`. Потом сохраняю байты картинки в `buf`, и после этого пытаюсь загрузить их на сервер. (Код приведен ниже)

Проблема в том, что сервер почему-то не воспринимает эти байты, хотя `buf.seek` я сделал, и если этот буфер сохранить в файл (т.е сделать `open('1.png', 'wb').write(buf.getvalue())` все сохраняется.)

```
buf = io.BytesIO()
plt.savefig(buf, format='png')
buf.seek(0)

picture = {'photo': buf.getvalue()}
req = requests.post(url, files=picture)
buf.close()
```

Comment: Что означает "сервер не воспринимает"? Приведенный вами кусок кода корректен и `requests` успешно создаст `multipart/form-data` запрос.

Comment: vk api некорректно воспринимает

Comment: этого явно недостаточно, приведите пример вашего кода на сервере - с отправкой все в порядке.